# getting This version of macOS 10.12.6 cannot be installed on this computer

Tags: macos

I have MacBook Pro (13inch Mid 2010) with Model Identifier MacBookPro7.1

As per apple document I can install macOS sierra and HighSierra. But, apparently I keep getting the above issue.

I used a normal procedure 
1 - going to app store and click on free upgrade button. 
2 - downloaded a copy of installer and tried to install

I already have el capitan installed on it.

Comment: Please describe how you are going about trying to install it...

Comment: Which version of OS X are you running now?

Comment: I have updated answer

Comment: 'Upgrade button' should have been to High Sierra, not Sierra. You can usually only find Sierra by searching the App Store, because it's not the current release.

Comment: Yes, even HighSierra is also not getting installed.

Comment: How certain are you it's the 2010? The 2009 is max OS El Cap, the 2010 is 'current'. Check on [Ultimate Mac Lookup](https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/)